# Warning messaged from ESLint when using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

I'm currently updating my application to React 16.8 so I can use the awesome new hook feature. Updating the React package (and all the dependencies) was not a problem and everything works fine. But when I try to setup ESLint it keeps giving me te following error when I'm trying to use hooks:

> React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "projectInfo" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

My component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

const myComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return <span onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>{counter}</span>;
};

export default myComponent;
```

My `.eslintsrc` file looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "plugins": [
        "react-hooks"
      ],
    "rules": {
        "no-console": ["warn", { "allow": ["info", "error"] }],
        "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
        "semi": ["warn", "always"],
        "no-debugger": ["warn"],
        "eqeqeq": ["warn"],
        "no-else-return": ["warn"],
        "no-extra-bind": ["warn"],
        "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": false,
        "prefer-destructuring": [
            "warn",
            {
                "array": true,
                "object": true
            },
            {
                "enforceForRenamedProperties": false
            }
        ],
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "warn"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
In the error it says that there is an error in `projectInfo`. For simplicity reasons I changed that with the `myComponent` code above. The projectinfo looked like this:

```
const projectInfo = props => {
  const [createdLink, setCreatedLink] = useState(null);
  const [getProjectStatus, asyncGetProject] = useAsyncCall(props.getProject);
  const [generateLinkStatus, asyncGenerateLink] = useAsyncCall(api.questionnaire.generateQuestionnaireToken);

  // ComponentWillMount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.project) {
      asyncGetProject(props.match.params.id);
    }
  }, []);

  const generateQuestionnaireLink = async () => {
    const response = await asyncGenerateLink(props.project.questionnaireId);
    const createdLink = `${window.location.host}/questionnaire/${response.data.id}`;
    setCreatedLink(createdLink);
  };

  const { translate, project, updateProject } = props;
  const errorMessage = generateLinkStatus.error.message || getProjectStatus.error.message;
  return (
    <div className={styles.profileContainer}>
      <Message message={errorMessage} status={'error'} />
      <BackButton />
      <Loading isVisible={getProjectStatus.loading} />
      {project && (
        <Fragment>
          <EditableForm entity={project} onSubmit={updateProject}>
            <Label text={translate('projectName')} name={'name'} />
            <Checkbox text={translate('isPublic')} name={'isPublic'} />
          </EditableForm>
          <Loading isVisible={generateLinkStatus.loading} />
          <Button text={translate('generateButton')} clickHandler={generateQuestionnaireLink} />
          <br />
          {createdLink && <span>{createdLink}</span>}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    translate: getTranslate(state.locale),
    project: state.project.currentProject
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getProject: id => dispatch(actions.getProject(id)),
    updateProject: (id, params) => dispatch(actions.updateProject(id, params))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(projectInfo);
```

Comment: what is "projectInfo" ? can you show the code of "projectInfo" ?

Comment: I added the projectInfo component in the question. See the Edit section

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is your component name starting with a lowercase letter.

See [eslint-plugin-react-hooks code source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/aa9423701e99a194d65a8b835882502902a65a50/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/RulesOfHooks.js#L43)

```
/**
 * Checks if the node is a React component name. React component names must
 * always start with a non-lowercase letter. So `MyComponent` or `_MyComponent`
 * are valid component names for instance.
 */

function isComponentName(node) {
  if (node.type === 'Identifier') {
    return !/^[a-z]/.test(node.name);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```